# In Linux, is concept of Process similar to Container (in microservices?)

Tags: process, cpu-architecture, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Process is executing an instance of an application.
Every process got its State, ID, address space etc, and isolated to each other.
It looks similar to Container that runs a specific service?
In some aspect, parallel programming is very similar as distributed programming?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this question is. Is this for some kind of written assignment? Can you please explain to what specific problem your question is related?

Comment: Not only similar but the same :)

Answer (score 1):

A container is a way of running a process/set of processes which are grouped together and have limited resources/accesses limitsset aside to isolate them. (Generally there is more isolation enforced between containers then regular processes)

Parallell programming and distributed programming are similar. In parallel programming the threads generally run on the same system, so they can access the same memory - in distributed programming this is not necessarily the case - ie threads are more separated, and things like network latency and shared object caches need to be taken into account as well.